# Globally Make Python Dictionaries Ordered

Tags: python

I want to be able to globally make dictionaries ordered.

I often find myself writing code like this:

```
things_to_evaluate = {
    'thing 1': lambda: Thing(property = 'a'), 
    'thing 2': lambda: Thing(property = 'b'), 
    ...
    }

...

for k, v in things_to_evaluate.iteritems():
     thing = v()
     result[k] = thing.process(something)
```

In my case, the dictionary syntax is a convenient way to specify a bunch of experiments I want to try.  Now, I'd like to actually have the results appear in the order I specified them.

I know that this is a terrible thing to want, and I know about hashing and unordered collections and the existence of OrderedDict and everything.

Still, it would be nice if I had the option to just for my own convenience, with one line of code, override some primitive function and make it so all dicts were ordered, consequences be damned.

So, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the OrderedDict?

Comment: Too many brackets. `{'a': 1', 'b': 2}` vs `OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])`.  I want the syntactic convenience of dict and the behaviour of OrderedDict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this, at least not without hacking up the source code to your favorite Python implementation and rebuilding it. (And, if your favorite implementation is CPython, this will be a huge amount of work, because `OrderedDict` not only isn't a builtin, it doesn't even have a C implementation—although that might change in 3.5.)

You can, of course, rebind the name `dict` to `collections.OrderedDict`, either globally (within your module) or super-globally (within builtins), but that isn't going to affect literal dictionary displays, dictionary comprehensions, builtin code that returns dictionaries (which includes things like the `type` function that constructs class and object `__dict__` and the interpreter code that handles `**kwargs`), etc.

You *could* invent your own way of writing `OrderedDict` displays and comprehensions, and use an import hook with an AST transformer to convert them into calls to the `OrderedDict` constructor. I believe `OrderedDict` displays are one of the samples that comes with [`MacroPy`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy), and it shouldn't be too hard to expand that to handle comprehensions as well. But without something like that, the best you're going to do is either:

```
from collections import OrderedDict as o

things_to_evaluate = o(
    ('thing 1', lambda: Thing(property = 'a')), 
    ('thing 2', lambda: Thing(property = 'b')), 
    ...
    )
```

… or:

```
def o(*args):
    return OrderedDict(zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))

things_to_evaluate = o(
    'thing 1', lambda: Thing(property = 'a'),
    'thing 2', lambda: Thing(property = 'b'),
    ...
    )
```

Comment: Alright, sounds like hacking into the Abstract Syntax Tree is would take more time than all the brackets I could ever type in my life and make my code unportable to boot.  But your second suggestion is nice.  I might even do something horrible like adding `__builtins__['odict'] = lambda *args: OrderedDict(zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))` in an `__init__.py`

Comment: @Peter: That's not a good way to add a builtin. In some contexts `__builtins__` is the module, not its dict, and in others it doesn't exist at all, and that changes between implementations and versions. Just import the module `__builtin__` (2.x) or `builtins` (3.x) and monkeypatch it normally. That works in any context in any implementation with a built-in module dict, and gives you an obvious error in any implementation which doesn't.

Comment: @Peter: Also, it's worth looking at MacroPy at least just to see what it can do, even if you decide not to use its odict display macro in your real code. And keep in mind that my hack at the end has a serious flaw: because you're not alternating commas and colons, an easy-to-make and hard-to-see typo gives you painful-to-debug incorrect data instead of an obvious `SyntaxError`. Still, it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

If order is important use a list rather than a dictionary. You might not need the keys at all!

If you do need the key, you can make your list contain 2-tuples (key-value pairs). The list and tuple literal syntax can do this for you without any hacking of the system internals:

```
things_to_evaluate = [
    ('thing 1', lambda: Thing(property = 'a')), 
    ('thing 2', lambda: Thing(property = 'b')),
    ...
    ]

...

for k, v in things_to_evaluate:
    thing = v()
    result.append((k, thing.process(something)))
```

Comment: I suspect if he already knows about `OrderedDict`, he (a) also already knows about lists, and (b) does need to use these things as dicts as well as ordered collections. And there's really no major advantage to using a list of pairs over an `OrderedDict`. It does save a bit of memory, but it makes the API more complicated to use, and means you give up key lookup.